# Flutter How to show list by for loop

Tags: flutter

I have created a simple list to show it by for loop.

```
List categories = [
  {
    {
      'CatID': '0',
      'CatName': 'All'
    },
    {
      'CatID': '1',
      'CatName': 'Computer Hardware'
    },
    {
      'CatID': '2',
      'CatName': 'Computer Software'
    },
  }
];
```

then i define a widget like this

```
List<Widget> CatWidget = List<Widget>();
```

Then i use it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  CatWidget.add(
    Container(
      child: Text(categories[i]['CatName']),
    ),
  );
}
```

Its showing error `Class '_CompactLinkedHashSet<Map<String, String>>' has no instance method '[]'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list contains too many braces:

```
List categories = [
    {
      'CatID': '0',
      'CatName': 'All'
    },
    {
      'CatID': '1',
      'CatName': 'Computer Hardware'
    },
    {
      'CatID': '2',
      'CatName': 'Computer Software'
    },
  ];
```

And your loop should run to **3** not **8** because you don't *have* 8.

So the following would work, however, I do encourage you to check the other answer for a better approach in general:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {

    List categories = [
  
    {
      'CatID': '0',
      'CatName': 'All'
    },
    {
      'CatID': '1',
      'CatName': 'Computer Hardware'
    },
    {
      'CatID': '2',
      'CatName': 'Computer Software'
    },
  ];

final catWidget = List<Widget>(); 

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  catWidget.add(
    Container(
      child: Text(categories[i]['CatName']),
    ),
  );
}

  runApp(MyApp(catWidget));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  
  const MyApp(this.children);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: children),
        ),
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you look on this question also please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087456/flutter-color-not-chaning-on-change-of-index

Answer (score 3):

You can use list.generate to loop through your list and return a widget.

```
 Column(
            children: List.generate(
              tags.length,
              (index) => Container(
                // margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
                child: NativeButton(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: sizeConfig.height(.01),
                    horizontal: sizeConfig.width(.02),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                  child: Text(tags[index]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a JSON array, inside the JSON array, you have a JSON Object and inside that JSON object, you have multiple JSON objects, which you want to iterate one by one, which is inappropriate.

JSON Array > JSON Objects **True**

JSON Array > JSON Array > JSON Object(s) **True**

JSON Array > JSON Object > JSON Object(s) **False**

For loop can work only on array or list of objects and the json should be like:

```
  [
    {
      'CatID': '0',
      'CatName': 'All'
    },
    {
      'CatID': '1',
      'CatName': 'Computer Hardware'
    },
    {
      'CatID': '2',
      'CatName': 'Computer Software'
    },
  ]
```